# primefaces inputtext anycharacter except whitespace

Tags: jsf, primefaces

how I can make for an inputText accept any letter except allow spaces and special characters?

i tried like this, but is not working...

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/private/commonHomeTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="someForm">
<p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000" autoUpdate="true"/>
<p:panelGrid style="100%">
<p:row>
<p:column style="350px">title</p:column>
<p:column>
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.somePropertie}" >
<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
</h:inputText>
</p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>  
</h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, do you want your inputText to accept letters from a-z and A-Z but not spaces and special characters? What are the special characters you don't want to accept?

Comment: thanks i wont accents tildes, etc... #$%&/()=" all that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression seems to be fine, to see error validation you have to include the `<h:message />` tag inside the `<h:form />` tag

```
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.somePropertie}" id="userInputField">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:message for="userInputField" />
```

Remember that you cannot use nested `<h:form />` inside a JSF page.

Comment: Thanks, i did what u said but its not working anyway :(

Comment: Have you checked to no have any nested <h:form /> inside your code? Are you sure to refresh the <h:message /> tag after page submit? How do you submit the data and how do you use the fragment of xhtml you posted?

Comment: i got it.. its working, in fact was a nested form.... sorry i didnt see it !!! its possible do this onkeypress event?

Comment: On which tag do you want to catch the onkeypress event?

Comment: on the same input, I do not expect a sumbit to allow the characters, I was checking onkeypress as in this example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596334/how-to-disable-special-characters-and-alphabets-in-primefaces-input-text but i still cant modify to my purpose...

Comment: It´s solved, i replace just the function of the example mentioned, something like this: var onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
   
   function lettersOnly(evt) {
   
     var theEvent = evt || window.event;       
     var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      
     if( !onlyLetters.test(key) ) {
         theEvent.returnValue = false;
         if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
     }
           
   }  Thanks 4 ur help!!! :D