# Unable to enter only Mobile Number in inputText with Country Code Not Other Chars in primefaces : +NN-NNNNNNNNNN

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to make input text box in primefaces which only can take mobile number with country code. The format is +NN-NNNNNNNNNN, e.g., +91-9876123456. User could not type any other characters except the mentioned. I've tried with some Javascript, but the result did not satisfy me.
By, [How to disable special characters and alphabets in Primefaces input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596334/how-to-disable-special-characters-and-alphabets-in-primefaces-input-text)

In this question, they have mentioned all the thing is perfect, but delete and movement of cursor is not happened here.

Moreover I do not want to use inputMask, behavior of this component is not exact with the text, although you have any better suggestion with this component then kindly provide.

Comment: You can use a regex pattern like `\+\d{1,2}-\d{10}`

Comment: Kasra kindly tell me with elaborately or with an example. I need to restrict user to type others chars in the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match that exact pattern, I would probably check on every keypress. Just make sure it's clear to the user that they need to match a pattern or they may get annoyed when their keys don't seem to work.

```js
$("#test").on("keypress", function(e) {
    var match = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57];
    var insert = '';
    if (this.value.length >= 14) {
      return false;
    }
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
      if (e.which === 43) {
        return true;
      }
      insert = '+'
    }
    if (this.value.length === 3) {
      if (e.which === 45) {
        return true;
      }
        insert = "-";
    }
    if (match.indexOf(e.which) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
    this.value += insert;
    return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test"></input>
```

Comment: Tried to run this code by "Run code snippet" but I could not type anything in the textbox.

Comment: You have to type the + first, per your requirements. We could make the + and - autofill instead, which probably makes more sense :)

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect with my requirement

Comment: Can you tell me it is working for Primefaces?
I've faced some problem to do this in Primefaces.
Function is not called from the 
<p:inputText id="mobileNo" required="true" label=""
  requiredMessage="Mobile number is required">
               <p:watermark value="+91-9000000000" for="mobileNo" />           
</p:inputText>

Comment: Used jQuery like this

$("#{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}:advocateRegistration:mobileNo").on("keypress", function(e) {
    alert("test");
    var match = [ 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57 ];
    var insert = '';
    if (this.value.length >= 14) {
     return false;
    }
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
     if (e.which === 43) {
      return true;
     }
 insert = '+'
 }
 if (this.value.length === 3) {
 if (e.which === 45) {
  return true;
 }
  insert = "-";
 }
 if (match.indexOf(e.which) === -1) {
  return false;
 }
 this.value += insert;
 return true;
});

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at Forza, they did some really interesting implementation for phone input with forced synthax like +(**)** ____ ____ :

http://forza.ndevrstudios.com/#/form-masks

Comment: thanx for the reply. I've also used the inputmask in Primefaces. but I do not want to show the underline, +, (, ) in the text box.